# Docker compose for mysql and spring app gives access denied

Tags: java, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose for `MySQL + Spring boot` app:

This is how my `docker-compose.yaml` looks like

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  docker-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'pass'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'test'
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  my-app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - docker-mysql
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
restart: on-failure
```

And this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
EXPOSE 8080
ADD /target/app-0.0.1.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

This is the `application.properties` of my app:

```
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql:3306/test?characterEncoding=utf8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

But when i run the containers with `docker-compose up` application encounter with access denied:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'172.20.0.3' (using password: NO)
```

In the log file, mysql created with an empty password!

```
[Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password !
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you following properties should be changed to use the user and pass, you defined in docker-mysql.

```
spring.datasource.password=pass
```

Also, add the `links` option in your spring-boot app.

```
depends_on:
  - docker-mysql
links:
  - docker-mysql
```

I don't think it matters, but the examples on the documentation uses the password without quotes. If above fails, try that as well.

Comment: `links` is not necessary on any version of Docker/Compose new enough to use a `version: "3"` YAML file.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.. Since I no longer uses links since I moved on to networks as recommended by docker, did not keep up with the update.

Answer (score 0):

You need mysql access with user root , so Run below command with mysql root user :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'172.20.0.3'
    IDENTIFIED BY 'pass' 
    WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Please check!

Comment: @Sajad : You need to run this command from mysql command prompt.

Comment: This may be necessary whey you use native mysql. But, not necessary when you are using docker mysql. Docker mysql is supposed to and do work as is without the need for such extra works.